# How do i stop my textures from being pink

Tags: texturing

[image]

I'm not exactly sure why some of it is pink and some of it is not, because I haven't done anything to it yet, how can I make that pink act like that colored eyelid?
*(The color that is already there was put there in supping mode not shading.)*
It is also all one object

Comment: Pink color indicates missing texture. In tha shader editor you didn't add a texture file.